# block "GET - On the App Store" link ads in Mobile Safari

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-safari, privacy, adblock

A lot of mobile optimised web sites display App Store links on the top of the page.

[image]

How to block this annoying ads? I already run and ad blocker for iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m afraid the answer is you can’t block them, at least not through a setting in iOS or a Content Blocker extension for Safari. There are [patches available for jailbroken devices](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/annoying-banner-ads-at-top-of-web-pages.1561440/) though.

These ads are shown through the [“Smart App Banners” feature of Safari](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html). As far as I know, there is no setting in iOS to turn them off. Because of the way [Safari Content Blocker extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Extensions/Conceptual/ContentBlockingRules/Introduction/Introduction.html) work, I also don’t think they can block the HTML tag that tells Safari to display the ad.

I might just be wrong, but other sources (see: [blog post](https://www.macslocum.com/2013/01/06/smart-app-banners-in-ios-be-gone/), [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/ios/comments/2fostg/can_i_turn_off_app_suggestions_in_safari/)) also indicate these banners can’t be easily disabled.

At least Safari does seem to remember that you don’t want to see an ad for a particular app (or on a particular site, I’m not sure) if you close the banner using the “⨯” button on the left.